# Orchard CMS - Settings.txt exclude webdeploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, orchardcms, microsoft-web-deploy

How to exclude the \App_Data\orchard\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt from a webdeploy of Orchard CMS (compiled from source)

Have tried a number of different file paths, and a straight Settings.txt.  It always uploads again.

[image]

settings

[image]

all works

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
<FilesToIncludeForPublish>OnlyFilesToRunTheApp</FilesToIncludeForPublish>
<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>orchard\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
```

This doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the "Exclude files from the App_Data folder" on the first screen? 
Actually, you don't need to copy this folder at all from your local machine when doing site updates.

Apart from Settings.txt, the App_Data folder also holds Logs and dependent assemblies (discovered dynamically by Orchard). You don't want to override those with your local copies too, so excluding the whole App_Data is a way to go. Or maybe you have a specific reason for not doing that?